# How to free an array in C/C++

Tags: c++, c, memory-management, memory-leaks

```
int main() {
    // Will this code cause memory leak?
    // Do I need to call the free operator?
    // Do I need to call delete?
    int arr[3] = {2, 2, 3};
    return 0;
}
```

1. Does this code create a memory leak?
2. Where does `arr` reside? On the stack or in RAM?

Comment: C and C++ are two completely different languages. Which one are you using?

Answer (score 12):

In this program

```
int main() {
    // Will this code cause memory leak?
    // Do I need to call the free operator?
    // Do I need to call delete?
    int arr[3] = {2, 2, 3};
    return 0;
}
```

array `arr` is a local variable of function main with the automatic storage duration. It will be destroyed after the function finishes its work.

The function itself allocated the array when it was called and it will be destroyed afetr exiting the function.

There is no memory leak.

You shall not call neither C function free nor the operator delete [].

If the program would look the following way

```
int main() {
    int *arr = new int[3] {2, 2, 3};
    //...
    delete [] arr;
    return 0;
}
```

then you should write operator delete [] as it is shown in the function.

Comment: How does the delete operator know the size of the array?

Comment: @Dr.Programmer - Probably by magic. The language standard doesn't say *how* it works, just that it *must* work. In practice, the size is stored somewhere, but we shouldn't bother.

Comment: @Dr.Programmer Usually it is implemented such a way that the compiler appends a prefix to the memory blcok that contains the the number of elements in the array.

Answer (score 5):

You have to call `free` only for objects you have created with `malloc`, and `delete` for those you've created with `new`.

In this case you don't need to do anything, this variable is managed automatically. As soon as it goes out of scope (i.e., in this case at the end of `main()`) its memory will be freed automatically.

So:

1. No, there are no memory leaks here.
2. The question doesn't make much sense. *All* variables are in RAM. The stack is just a special part of the RAM memory, which is managed in a way that results fast and efficient to deal with function calls, automatic allocation/deallocation of local variables, etc. Anyway, yes, `arr` is created on the stack, whereas variables created using `malloc` or `new` are said to be on the "free store" or "heap".

Comment: Thank's for the clarification. If I were to initialize a const char * str = "abc" or char str [] = "abc", Would that reside on the stack as well?

Answer (score 4):

The stack *is* in RAM.

No, it doesn't leak memory.
Yes, the array will normally be "on the stack" (i.e., wherever the implementation allocates local variables, which is required to have stack-like behavior, even though the hardware might not provide direct support for a stack).

Comment: Thank's for the clarification. If I were to initialize a const char * str = "abc" or char str [] = "abc", Would that reside on the stack as well?

Comment: Assuming the first was inside a function, the pointer would be allocated as a local, but the string literal would be statically allocated (e.g., usually in an initialized data segment). In the second, you'd have a string literal that was statically allocated, and an array that was locally allocated. The string literal would be used to initialize the local array upon entry to the function (or whatever block) in which it was located.

Answer (score 0):

No memory leak is caused since `arr` is a local variable (and is therefore located on the stack) and goes out of scope when the closing curly brace of `main` is reached. This implies the absence of the need to call `free` or `delete`.

You seem to misunderstand the term "RAM." It just means "Random Access Memory", which can refer to every kind of randomly accessible memory, commonly a PC's main memory. The stack is just as well part of RAM as the free store or (runtime part of ) the OS is.

Comment: Thank's for the clarification. If I were to initialize a const char * str = "abc" or char str [] = "abc", Would that reside on the stack as well?

Comment: @Dr.Programmer String literals are **not** stored on the stack, except if used to initialize an array like `char str[] = "abc";`. So your first example isn't on the stack but probably in read-only memory together with the program code or some data, your second example is on the stack.

Comment: @Dr.Programmer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2589949/c-string-literals-where-do-they-go