# Is this the right way to delete an array in a destructor?

Tags: c++

I hope you're all having a good day!
So I want to create a class which saves a word (string) as a character array. 
I allocated memory to str in the default constructor, not sure if that's how it works.

```
`   #include <iostream>
    using namespace std;
    class String{
      private:
      char *str;
      public:
      String(){
        str=new char[10];
        str="Hello";
      }
      void getstr(){
        for (int i=0;i<5;i++){
          cout<<str[i];
        }
      }
      ~String(){
        delete []str;
      }
    };
    int main(){
      String s1;
      s1.getstr();
      return 0;
    }
```

When i run this program, it does print "Hello" but this is the exact output:

```
*** Error in `./main': free(): invalid pointer: 0x0000000000400ab5 ***
Hello
```

When i removed the destructor part, it worked fine,but i need to free the memory allocated to str,right? Any help?

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Perhaps use `std::string`? Also this `str="Hello";` does not make sense

Comment: `char str[100];` is followed by `str=new char[10];`, and then, surprisingly enough, by `str="Hello";`. What's going on here?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to free an array in C/C++](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33335668/how-to-free-an-array-in-c-c)

Comment: @ForceBru i accidently wrote `str[100]` in the question, it was actually `*str` when i compiled it.

Answer (score 3):

```
    str=new char[10];
    str="Hello";
```

The first line allocates a new `char` array which can hold 10 chars (or 9 chars and a null byte). The second line however, sets the pointer `str` to the address of your string literal `"Hello"`. Thus, when you call `delete []`, you are trying to free a pointer to string literal and not a pointer to some dynamically allocated memory. If you want your string to be dynamically allocated, you should copy your string (preferably using [strcpy](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strcpy/)), or just use `std::string`, which will take care of memory management for you.

Comment: I want to do it without using 'string'. Is there a way i can do that?

Comment: @Zarish the answer is right there: "you should copy your string (preferably using strcpy)"

Comment: @Zarish - And after fixing the constructor, you should also look into adding a copy constructor and an assignment operator. Otherwise you will soon get "double delete" errors. (Or just use a `std::string` which takes care of everything :-).

Comment: Also, if you are using C++… then why don't want to use string? There is nothing wrong or slow in it.